Debian Bookworm - How to prevent block device seeking and probing when connected?
I have a small bootable system which requires access to storage devices, but not at the data level (i.e. just firmware commands), with the exception of a USB floppy drive whose data is accessed raw (no filesystem, just dd).
Problems are generated from this behaviour as:

Some storage devices are locked which causes firmware errors when read operations are attempted
The seeking of the USB floppy is not required and prolongs the boot process

I've tried the following commands:
systemctl disable systemd-udev-trigger.service
systemctl disable systemd-udevd.service

systemctl mask systemd-udev-trigger.service
systemctl mask systemd-udevd.service

systemctl stop systemd-udev-trigger.service
systemctl stop systemd-udevd.service

This however results in no block device being created upon the connection of any devices. I understand that udisks2 may once have been used, however it is not present on my particular system. It looks like blkid might be responsible for the access of block devices as I read that it attempts to "locate/print block device attributes". If this is the cause then I'm unsure how to disable it.
Solutions requiring hardcoding of block devices (e.g. /dev/sda) are not possible as I don't know what designation the devices be given.
It looks like this question may be related to the issue(s) I'm having, but its solutions involve kernel modification which, if it's getting into all that, I'd rather just put up with the extra ten or so seconds and irritating repetitive floppy seek noises!
How might these read operations be prevented whilst still being able to access the device as a block device? Thanks
